# A open source app I'm testing is hiding an activity class, how?

Tags: android

I'm testing an open source demo application, that has 1 activity visible in main -> java -> mypackage and another activity that is hidden. I've tried searching for the Strings that the EditText uses and it's in a yellow values.xml folder.

Is it possible to view the source code for that hidden activity class? I'm also confused why they made the project open source, but decide to hide an Activity implementation.

[image]

[image]

I traced the hidden activity all the way to the button call that starts the hidden activity:

```
private Runnable onPayWithCardClickListener;

payWithCardButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      dialog.dismiss();
      showing = false;
      onPayWithCardClickListener.run();
    });
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

The open source app: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-android-quickstart

Comment: your code shows an interface, not sure where the hidden activity is?

Comment: payWithCardButton is the button that opens this activity. I am also not sure how this Runnable starts a hidden activity, I've never seen this before.

Comment: are you referring to _startCardEntryActivity_ in here: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/in-app-payment/android/sqip/CardEntry.html

Comment: No. I literally can't find the layout xml of the picture above any where in the source code. https://i.imgur.com/haimwQk.png I click the "Pay with card" button and it brings me to the page above. But theres literally no code referencing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runnable `onPayWithCardClickListener` actually fires the following snippet :

```
private void startCardEntryActivity() {
    CardEntry.startCardEntryActivity(this);
}
```

Out of which `CardEntry` is an import of `sqip` (as per the import statement `import sqip.CardEntry;`)

So, you just need to lookup the source code for `sqip` and especially `CardEntry`. I gave a quick search and found [this FTP entry (https://sdk.squareup.com/public/android/com/squareup/sdk/in-app-payments/card-entry/1.4.0/) they suggest in their doc.

`CardEntry.kt` shows the following code :

```
package sqip

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.annotation.MainThread
import sqip.CardEntry.handleActivityResult
import sqip.internal.CardEntryActivity

/**
 * Lets the application collect card information from the customer.
 */
object CardEntry {

  internal var cardNonceBackgroundHandler: CardNonceBackgroundHandler? = null

  const val DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE = 0xCA4D

  /**
   * Starts an activity that lets the application collect card information from the customer.
   *
   * @see [handleActivityResult] to handle the result of the card entry activity.
   *
   * @param activity The activity instance from which to start the card entry activity.
   * @param collectPostalCode Indicates that the customer must enter the postal code associated with their payment card.
   *                          When false, the postal code field will not be displayed. Defaults to true.
   * @param requestCode This code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits. The default value is [DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE].
   *
   * @note Postal code collection is required for processing payments for Square accounts based in the United States, Canada, and United Kingdom.
   * Disabling postal code collection in those regions will result in all credit card transactions being declined.
   */
  @MainThread
  @JvmStatic
  @JvmOverloads
  fun startCardEntryActivity(
    activity: Activity,
    collectPostalCode: Boolean = true,
    requestCode: Int = DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE
  ) {
    CardEntryActivity.start(activity, collectPostalCode, requestCode)
  }

  /**
   * ******************* BETA API *******************
   * Starts an activity that lets the application collect gift card information from the customer.
   *
   * @see [handleActivityResult] to handle the result of the card entry activity.
   *
   * @param activity The activity instance from which to start the card entry activity.
   * @param requestCode This code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits. The default value is [DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE].
   */
  @MainThread
  @JvmStatic
  @JvmOverloads
  fun startGiftCardEntryActivity(
    activity: Activity,
    requestCode: Int = DEFAULT_CARD_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE
  ) {
    CardEntryActivity.startGiftCardFlow(activity, requestCode)
  }

  /**
   * Use this function to handle results of the card entry activity. This function should be called
   * from [Activity.onActivityResult] with the provided data parameter.
   * [callback] will be called immediately with the result of the card entry activity.
   *
   * The callback is executed on the main thread.
   *
   * @param data The data parameter from [Activity.onActivityResult]. May be null.
   * @param callback A callback that will be immediately called back, if [data] corresponds to the
   * result of a card entry activity.
   */
  @MainThread
  @JvmStatic
  fun handleActivityResult(
    data: Intent?,
    callback: Callback<CardEntryActivityResult>
  ) {
    CardEntryActivity.onActivityResult(data, callback)
  }

  /**
   * Sets an optional handler that will be called from a background thread with the card result,
   * before the card entry activity finishes. This allows the application to perform additional
   * work such as attempting to charge the card and offers the ability to retry
   * (for instance in case of a network error).
   */
  @JvmStatic
  fun setCardNonceBackgroundHandler(handler: CardNonceBackgroundHandler) {
    cardNonceBackgroundHandler = handler
  }
}
```

Comment: But how did you figure out ```onPayWithCardClickListener``` runs ```startCardEntryActivity()```? Maybe it's just because I'm a newb, but it doesn't seem like it says anywhere in the Java class that it runs that method.

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE the way I found it was by going to the github project and searching for the listener onPayWithCardClickListener which is what you had in your snippet. I found the method used to set that listener as _setOnPayWithCardClickListener_. I searched for the use of the latter and found the _startCardEntryActivity_ which then points to _CardEntry_

Comment: I saw the snippet you shown was from `OrderSheet.java`. The variable `onPayWithCardClickListener` is set by `setOnPayWithCardClickListener`, so I searched which Activity is calling that method. Turns out `CheckoutActivity.java` does, and it passes `this::startCardEntryActivity` as argument. I looked up that method in the current Activity, and the method is what I pasted in the answer. Step by step, basically.

Comment: I unfortunately can't find the sqip class anywhere though. https://i.imgur.com/HQTtUq0.png CTRL + SHIFT + F to search entire project, No sqip or CardEntry class :/

Comment: Yes, you won't find it because it's compiled as a third-party library. The code I pasted and the URL I gave you points to the original source code.